# Llamar a otra clase con RunOnUiThread

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, hilos

Puedo cambiar de Layout `(StartActivity(Intent) )` de una forma mas optima que esta?:

```
     finally
     {
      RunOnUiThread(() =>
           {
           var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Class#2));
           StartActivity(Intent);
                    });
                    this.Finish();
           }
```

Sucede que con este método (en ocasiones) la app se queda en negro y muestra el mensaje:

> The system ui is not responding
>
> | Esperar || Cerrar App |

Y me supongo es debido a que "congela" el `UI Thread.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hay comentarios poco utiles y luego esta el suyo. Mejor hubiera recomendado una lectura para el problema que plantee no le parece?

Comment: `Hay comentarios poco utiles y luego esta el suyo` -> Pues, eso depende de cómo lo interprete el lector: hay quienes se hieren y/o se enojan y/o se incomodan, y por el otro lado, hay quienes lo ven con otros ojos en buena onda, en este segundo grupo, aprovechan las recomendaciones mencionadas, modifican la pregunta agregando todos los datos que pueden ser necesarios para mejorar la pregunta de tal forma que se incremente la chance de obtener una respuesta, y ya :) `Mejor hubiera recomendado una lectura para el problema que plantee no le parece?` Sí, desconozco tu escenario y no sé qué sugerir.